# adding spring boot executable jar in a simple MVC web project and their use

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, soap, spring-ws

I have a situation where I have a simple MVC(JSPs and Servlets) application and I have to use a SOAP Client web service but this is made in spring boot and spring ws executable jar. I have to use this client in MVC application.
MVC application is so big and complicated that it can not be changed in spring and the vendor company can not change the soap client into some other ws client like axis1, axis2, jaxws etc.

But how can I use it.
How can I pass any java object to run an executable jar like java -jar springws.jar requestObject

Please provide suggestion

Comment: Why do you want to run the messy MVC app as a jar ? Which server you are using currently?

Comment: Weblogic server we are using. first of all  MVC app is not a jar I have to use spring ws client as a jar in MVC application for accessing soap client.